# robot setup tf setup for navigation

Tags: navigation, rviz, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I try to set an initial pose for 2d navigation RVIZ crashes on me.  When I check the tf tree, I see that odom is off to the side and not even connected.  /map connects straight to /base_link.  What am I doing wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10135/robot-setup-tf-setup-for-navigation-/) by [a11irap](https://answers.ros.org/users/596/a11irap/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-06-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [a11irap](https://answers.ros.org/users/596/a11irap/) on 2011-06-01**:
irobotcreate with a hokuyolaser.I amfollowing this tutorial [http://www.princeton.edu/~ctralie/Projects/DukeDusty2/Tutorial/#navigation.I](http://www.princeton.edu/%7Ectralie/Projects/DukeDusty2/Tutorial/#navigation.I) did view_frames again before I set initial pose and it seems like /odom is branching off /map now, but /base_link is branching off /map with the broadcaster /temp.

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2011-06-01**:
What type of robot are you using, and what packages are involved? It would sound as if your base controller/driver is publishing directly base_link to map rather than putting out an odometry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The first "temp" publisher is wrong. It says the robot does never move in the map.
Remove it totally.

The corresponding tf chain from map->odom->base_link should be produced by odometry and SLAM/localization, not a static_transform_publisher.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-06-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [a11irap](https://answers.ros.org/users/596/a11irap/) on 2011-06-02**:
That worked!  Thanks a lot man!